# Individual column filtering in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following datatable. I want to apply individual column filtering on each record. Please to tell me how to do that in this table

```
if ($("#example13") !== null) {
    $('#example13').DataTable({
        "stateSave": true,
         "language": {
            "searchPlaceholder": "Search",
            "lengthMenu": "Showing _MENU_ Users",
            "zeroRecords": "Sorry No user(s) found",
            "info": "Showing  _START_ of _END_ of _TOTAL_ Users",
            "infoEmpty": "Sorry No user(s) found ",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ TOTAL Users)"
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First place an search box on top or bottom of every column in datatable:

```
// var table= $('#example13').DataTable({..............
$('#example13 tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} );
```

Then bind the `column().search()` function of datatable on each column:

```
    table.columns().every( function () {     
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );
```